# How to maintain cropped information in pdf page after page extraction with itextsharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I am using acrobat 8.0 professional for cropping text from a PDF.
One page of Original pdf is

[image]

After cropping pdf above page is

[image]

In mine project i am using cropped pdf and extract individual pages from it by following code

```
private void ExtractPages(string inputFile, string outputFile, int start, int end)
        {
            // get input document
            PdfReader inputPdf = new PdfReader(inputFile);
            // retrieve the total number of pages
            int pageCount = inputPdf.NumberOfPages;
            if (end < start || end > pageCount)
            {
                end = pageCount;
            }

            //var pgSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(myWidth, myHeight);
            //var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(pgSize, leftMargin, rightMargin, topMargin, bottomMargin);

            // load the input document
            Document inputDoc = new Document(inputPdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));

            // create the filestream
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
            {
                // create the output writer
                PdfWriter outputWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(inputDoc, fs);
                inputDoc.Open();
                PdfContentByte cb1 = outputWriter.DirectContent;

                // copy pages from input to output document
                for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
                {
                    inputDoc.SetPageSize(inputPdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
                    inputDoc.NewPage();

                    PdfImportedPage page = outputWriter.GetImportedPage(inputPdf, i);
                    int rotation = inputPdf.GetPageRotation(i);

                    if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
                    {
                        cb1.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, inputPdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cb1.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
                inputDoc.Close();
            }
        }
```

Problem is that after page extraction cropping information is not retained in extracted pdf. Extracted pdf is same as original pdf with extra text in it.

How to retained cropped information in extracted pdf ?

Comment: Use the iTextSharp `PdfCopy` class for this task.

Comment: Plz provide some code.

Comment: Thanks i have found the solution by using PdfCopy.